# Marketing Cloud: How to Get Only the Required Fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Can anyone shade a light on how to use a ***Simple Query*** to request only the required fields of an asset with REST API. According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) we need to include **$fields** element in the querystring with a value

> Comma delimited string of asset properties used to reduce the size of
>   your results to only the properties you need.

I have tried this

> $fields='id,name'

but it does not eliminate the other fields.

The same problem exists in advanced query (check the request JSON below). The ***fields*** object is completely ignored.

```
{
    "page": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 50
    },
    "query": {
        "property": "sssetType.id",
        "simpleOperator": "equal",
        "value": 23
    },
    "fields": ["id",
    "name",
    "assetType",
    "createdDate",
    "modifiedDate",
    "category"],
    "sort": [{
        "property": "name",
        "direction": "ASC"
    },
    {
        "property": "modifiedDate",
        "direction": "DESC"
    }]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I can't seem to get this to work either (I don't think you need quotation marks in your parameter values). Also you should not need to use a Simple Query if you want to return all assets.

I note that if I include a `$fields` parameter, it does return fewer name/value pairs then if I omit this parameter, but it does not appear to limit to the fields that you specify. Looks like this is a bug.

It looks like you will need to parse the response payload and then use the name/value pairs that you need.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, I have tried with quotation marks and without them, it dose not work. I have never had so many problems with API than with Marketing Cloud. So many things do not work, I hope their developers are monitoring this forums for reported bugs.